# Eastbourne/Beachy Head with a toddler

Tags: uk, children

I am hoping to make a two-night trip to Eastbourne, to visit Beachy Head. I'll be accompanied by my wife and one-year old baby (most probably in a buggy). I'll take a train from London to Eastbourne, and from Eastbourne to Beachy Head I understand there is a bus service.

My questions are:

1. Is Beachy Head child-friendly?
2. The high-point of our visit will be the peak of Beachy Head, can I
   lug the buggy up to the peak?
3. How long is the trip to the peak, if I decide to carry the baby in a
   sling/carrier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Beachy Head Peace Path brochure](http://www.southdowns.gov.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/122992/Beachy-Head.pdf):

> Trails suitable for people with impaired mobility, wheelchairs, mobility scooters and push chairs
>   ...
>   The path is a firm and even surfaced track with no gates, stiles or steps.

The round trip path is 750 m in length, I can't imagine it would take more than an hour if you stop and smell the flowers.

Comment: I realised that there is an open-top bus (possibly City Sightseeing) that goes to the top. That would take a lot of work off me.